# How to access grid control in content page from base master page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

We have 3 levels of master pages inheritance:

Base Master Page -> Master Page 1 -> Master Page 2.

Master Page 2 has content page. That content page contains grid control.

How can I access grid control in content page from Base Master Page?

Answer (score 0):

Each control has `Controls` collection and `FindControl` method. 
Given that control is on the page you can use Page property of any Master Page , ie

```
  this.Page.FindControl("MyGrid")
```

in the code-behind of any master page you named.

UPDATE: In case controls are added dynamically you still can set ID property of such controls so using FindControl will still work.

Also as I said before, you can recursively walk through controls.
I belive answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594314/using-linq-how-do-you-get-all-label-controls/2594334#2594334) question will give you idea.

Here is a link to this method on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx)
Link to Page property description on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.page.aspx)

Comment: What's Page in: this.Page.FindControl("MyGrid") ?

Comment: Master Page is control. so it has `Page` property which reference current page.

Comment: The issue is that I load grid control dynamically and don't have permanent grid control ID. We have detail/view grids as well. So, how can I find right grid in that case?

Comment: well I updated answer with the link to Page property description.

Comment: Ok. I wrote this for test in Base Master Page: Page page = this.Page; and I've got page's ID = __Page. What's that? It's useless...

Comment: that is ID property of current page. what you were expecting to see there ?

Comment: What's current page? I need grid control in content page.

Comment: current page IS you content page. `FindControl` method will allow you to find control on you content page.

Comment: Ok. I've understood it. But, I can't see any place in our code where we set the grid's ID. Is there any other way how grid's ID could be set? Our grid is actually is placed inside user control, which is on content page and user control is loaded dynamically by using LoadControl method.

Comment: otherwise how are you going to distiguish grid you are looking for from another grid? if there is only one grid on the page, see link to another question and replace Label type with GridView in the answer to that.

Comment: We use this to load user control: var gridFrameControl = LoadControl("Controls/GridFrameControl.ascx") as GridFrameControl;

Comment: This: grid.ID = "blablabla" doesn't work. When I call this: Control control = this.Page.FindControl("gtk"); it returns null.

Comment: You may need to look recursively as FindControl only returns direct elements of Controls collection.

Comment: again check the link in my answer to another SO question.